# How to properly call UDF (external function) from Firebird database using Python fdb

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebird, firebird2.5

I am a beginner programmer (actually automated QA tester) working on an internal project (specific to my work) where I am trying to use a UDF (external function aka User Defined Function) that is stored in a Firebird database (I hope I phrased all that correctly).

I'm interfacing to the Firebird database using the fdb driver for Python, I can connect, run basic SQL statements, but when I run the following statement the UDF returns 0 instead of the expected value.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO temp (column1,column2) VALUES(f_udfName(?),?)",(int(line.rstrip('\n')),line.rstrip('\n')))
```

I'm traversing through a file and each line of the file is an 11-digit number. I am wanting to insert the original number into `column1` and the return value of the UDF into `column2` of the table `temp`. When I hit this line of code it completes successfully, but I get a return value of `0` instead of 9-digit number.

I have googled everything I could think of to figure this out. If someone would be able to point me in the correct direction at least, I would greatly appreciate it.

I am using Python 3.4, most recent fdb version, and Firebird 2.5.

**EDIT:** If I run the code from the python command line and do not parametrize the statement the UDF returns the expected value. Example:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO temp (column1,column2) VALUES(f_udfName(12345678901),12345678901)")
```

Comment: What happens if you use a real integer as parameter (instead of `line.rstrip('\n')`? Have you checked if the result of `line.rstrip('\n')` is the expected value? What happens if you use `f_udfName(CAST(? AS INTEGER))`?

Comment: Passing a real integer instead of the `line.rstrip('\n')` results in the same problem. I tested casting the parameter as a BIGINT and that resolved the problem!

Comment: And `line.rstrip('\n')` returns a string value, thank you for that solution!

Comment: I had failed to notice that your example literal values are 11 digits long. That value is out of range of `INTEGER` (-2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647), that is probably why `BIGINT` works, although I would expect the type to be inferred as `BIGINT` automatically if the UDF supports 64 bit integers; so it could be that you need to use the python `long(..)` function instead of `int(...)`, and everything else can stay the same.

Comment: I am using Python 3.4 so `long(..)` is no longer identified as a built-in function. It was merged into `int(..)`, I did initially try that causing me to find this.

Comment: Then something is probably wrong with the type inference in Firebird (maybe intentionally for backwards compatibility).

Comment: Do you think we can mark changing the SQL statement to `CAST` the parameter as a `BIGINT` as a solution? How should we proceed from here?

Comment: Yes, I suggest you post an answer with your solution and accept your own answer. I gave hints, but that was basically guess work that paid off ;).

Comment: Greatly appreciated sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As recommended by [Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926782/how-to-properly-call-udf-external-function-from-firebird-database-using-python#comment51780425_31926782), changing the SQL statement to `CAST` the parameter as a `BIGINT` resolved the problem.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO temp (column1,column2) VALUES(f_udfName(CAST(? AS BIGINT)),?)",(int(line.rstrip('\n')),line.rstrip('\n'))
```

Attempting to use the `long(..)` function in Python 3.4 did not work because as of Python 3.0.1 the `long(..)` function was merged into the `int(..)` function. Attempting to use `int(..)` will result in a return value of `0` without the `CAST` statement.